# Flutter: How to automatically update AppBar bottom height depending on child height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

`AppBar`s bottom property is of type `PreferredSizeWidget`, so I provide `PreferredSize` widget which requires in `preferredSize` property specify actual size to use. But I need not static number but automatically calculated depending on child, which in my case is `Wrap` widget. The problem is that height of `Wrap` can be determined only after `build` method is called using `RenderObject`.

What I have:

[image: have]

What I want(made by gif editing software):

[image: want]

[Code in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1abae3dbbc4210b23873f625f99fb22f)

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final items = List.generate(400, (index) => '$index');
  final filterOptions = <IntType>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: buildBody(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Simple filtering'),
          bottom: buildAppBarBottom(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody() {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = items[index];

          if (filterOptions.every((option) => item.contains(option.symbol))) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(item));
          }

          return Container(height: 0.0001);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget buildAppBarBottom() {
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),  // change height depending on the child height
      child: Wrap(
        spacing: 8,
        children: IntType.values.map((option) {
          return FilterChip(
            selectedColor: Colors.white,
            selected: filterOptions.contains(option),
            onSelected: (isSelected) {
              setState(() {
                if (isSelected) {
                  filterOptions.add(option);
                } else {
                  filterOptions.remove(option);
                }
              });
            },
            label: Text(option.name),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IntType {
  static const IntType one = const IntType._('One', '1');
  static const IntType two = const IntType._('Two', '2');
  static const IntType three = const IntType._('Three', '3');
  static const IntType four = const IntType._('Four', '4');
  static const IntType five = const IntType._('Five', '5');
  static const IntType six = const IntType._('Six', '6');
  static const IntType seven = const IntType._('Seven', '7');
  static const IntType eight = const IntType._('Eight', '8');
  static const IntType nine = const IntType._('Nine', '9');
  static const IntType zero = const IntType._('Zero', '0');

  final String name;
  final String symbol;

  const IntType._(this.name, this.symbol);

  static const values = [
    IntType.one,
    IntType.two,
    IntType.three,
    IntType.four,
    IntType.five,
    IntType.six,
    IntType.seven,
    IntType.eight,
    IntType.nine,
    IntType.zero,
  ];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to AKS answer
Workaround is to move `Wrap` to `Scaffold`'s body

[Updated code in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/63d437659aa213b7c23bc464f39c85f3)

Updated code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final items = List.generate(400, (index) => '$index');
  final filterOptions = <IntType>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0)),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: buildBody(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Simple filtering'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Material(
          elevation: 4,
          child: Container(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Wrap(
                alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                spacing: 8,
                children: IntType.values.map((option) {
                  return FilterChip(
                    selectedColor: Colors.white,
                    selected: filterOptions.contains(option),
                    onSelected: (isSelected) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (isSelected) {
                          filterOptions.add(option);
                        } else {
                          filterOptions.remove(option);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    label: Text(option.name),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = items[index];

                if (filterOptions
                    .every((option) => item.contains(option.symbol))) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text(item));
                }

                return Container(height: 0.0001);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class IntType {
  static const IntType one = const IntType._('One', '1');
  static const IntType two = const IntType._('Two', '2');
  static const IntType three = const IntType._('Three', '3');
  static const IntType four = const IntType._('Four', '4');
  static const IntType five = const IntType._('Five', '5');
  static const IntType six = const IntType._('Six', '6');
  static const IntType seven = const IntType._('Seven', '7');
  static const IntType eight = const IntType._('Eight', '8');
  static const IntType nine = const IntType._('Nine', '9');
  static const IntType zero = const IntType._('Zero', '0');

  final String name;
  final String symbol;

  const IntType._(this.name, this.symbol);

  static const values = [
    IntType.one,
    IntType.two,
    IntType.three,
    IntType.four,
    IntType.five,
    IntType.six,
    IntType.seven,
    IntType.eight,
    IntType.nine,
    IntType.zero,
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using bottomAppbar property,You should make a Column and add two children of which one is for simulation of *bottom appBar* and other for the *actual body* and add `wrap` widget in it,

This way you can get exact same widget structure without hindering the text inside the Appbar widget.

Hope perspective to this solution may help you.

Comment: I think I don't understand your solution. Why I need Container if I need add Wrap to body? I rather need Column. I tried to implement that but I can't achieving the same look and feel. I can't bring to work same elevation level as was before. There is trade-off, however, to remove it entirely, but it's not an option for me. Are you have solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right and your code is simply awesome, I just wanted to give you the feel to the solution. Are you still getting the elevation inconsistency? If it is plz upload a screenshot.

Comment: All is ok now. I "moved" elevation to Wrap, so it looks like Wrap is actually placed in AppBar bottom. You can try it yourself in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/63d437659aa213b7c23bc464f39c85f3)